# EventListeners in nested Functions

Tags: actionscript-3, function, addeventlistener, nested-function

I've got a few MouseEvent listeners outside of a function that contains nested functions that need to use the functions attached to the listeners.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, buttonOver); 

function navigation (): void {

    if statements;

    function buttonOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
        movieclip.play();
    }
}
```

I keep getting an "1120:Access of undefined property buttonOver" error. I know it's because the EventListener is outside of the function "navigation" but I need it to be accessed by other functions later. Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. I don't think you should nest functions. Why don't you use a class instead that you can access from other classes / instances?

Rob

Comment: Can you do multiple public functions inside of a class?

Comment: I'm beginning to see that I am so far behind on this its ridiculous. I miss the good ol' days of C++ and HTML.

Comment: Don't worry. You can do very cool things with Classes in ActionScript, and it's not that hard to get your head around it. Check out this tutorial, it should give you the idea: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html

Comment: i've been going back and rewriting my as without embedding functions. it's insane how much easier this has become. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Forget about nested and anonymous functions. And also forget about writing code in a frame. You can do everything you want without using them.

Comment: This was a separate .as file; no code is actually in the .fla. This is my first time back on AS since AS 1.0 so I'm moving pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the nested function in the first place. Everything will be a lot easier without nesting.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, buttonOver); 

function navigation (): void {

    if statements;
}
function buttonOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    movieclip.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe your looking to add and then remove the event listener according to some condition?

That seams to be the most common mistake for beginners when I see they are trying to nest event handlers.

```
function navigation (): void {
    if (somethingTrue){
        button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, buttonOver); 
    else if(somethingElseTrue){
        button1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, buttonOver);
    }  
}

function buttonOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    movieclip.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, your nested function is limited to the scope of the function it is defined in. Your attempt to access it outside of that function will throw an error. Relevant Adobe docs below:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html

Move your nested function outside of the function it is nested in, or change your listener to call `navigation` and ask `navigation` to call `buttonOver`